# Spring-boot Rest : Use ControllerAdvice but keep default handlers

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, controller-advice

My basic need was to catch user defined exceptions and return generic responses. For this I used the @ControllerAdvice with @ExceptionHandler. See example below

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler  {

    @ExceptionHandler(PersonNotFoundException.class)
    public void handleBadPostalCode(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), "Invalid person Id");
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public void handleDefault(Exception e, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(), "Unknown error happened");
    }
}
```

The PersonNotFoundException is handled as expected. But other exceptions default handlers are gone and only Http code without body is returned. Apparently this is the expected behaviour when extending ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.
I can override other default exceptions but this is not ideal.
Using a generic Exception.class handler will force me to return one HTTP Code for all of them.

SO i'm looking for a way to handle my own exceptions globally in the ControllerAdvice or similar without having to override default exception handlers

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest and the most cleaner way to handle it is just using `@ResponseStatus` on your exception class:

```java
 @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="No such Order")  // 404
 public class OrderNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
     // ...
 }
```

Also is extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` necessary? IMO it's not. You can handle it only by using `@ControllerAdvice` (or `@RestControllerAdvice`) and `@ExceptionHandler`

More over you can directly return your response in method without injecting `HttpServletResponse` and calling `send()` method. Take a look into [this](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) guide.